# Is there a way to delete a record from a text file by entering a student's ID?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Firstly, i'm new here so pls forgive me for any mistakes i make in the questions. :(

My assignment requires me to print to enter student ID and then delete that specific student's information and update the text file. I have 4 text files holding information of different student's, how can do that for each file?

I tried to follow many tutorials but nothing is working,there were some sample codes a well

expect the output to be 'deleted student record'but it didn't come about..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Share your txt file structure

Answer (score 1):

please be more specific about how the student data is stored in the 4 txt files you mentioned
the general thing you can do is

```
1.take the student_id from user
2.loop through the txt file   //you can use while loop
  read txt file txt_file_student_data_id
  copy the text file data to temporary file if student_id!=txt_file_student_data_id
  //use string comparison or integer depending upon id 
3.delete txt file
4.rename temporary file to txt file
5.do the same for remaining file
```